# Looking for tips on how to write a werewolf/mafia type story

Tags: fiction

I've been looking for tips on how to write a [werewolf/mafia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mafia_(party_game)) story, but when I use search terms such as mafia, werewolf, or mole, I just get stories about the mafia, werewolves, and moles (animal.) When I combine those search term I just stories about the mafia, werewolves, and moles (animal.) When I use the term social deduction story, I get a bunch of social deduction games. As you can imagine, when the thing you're trying to look up has a vastly more common definition than the definition you are trying to use, then finding what you want is hard. So, I'm looking for tips on how to write a werewolf/mafia story (as in trying to find out who amongst the group is actually an enemy.)

Comment: Be careful, for this can be viewed as brainstorming. Maybe give more details on your story?

Comment: What kind of advice do you want? The question seems too vague.

Comment: I think there are some murder mysteries based on the idea of a group of people getting stuck together somewhere and having to find the murderer among them. You could look to those for inspiration.

Comment: Your question is not really answerable. Are you looking for research tips...? or for someone's novel on the exact topic you want so you can rip it off...? Or a game on the exact topic you want that has a narrative?

Comment: I'm just looking for any general research tips.

Answer (score 1):

Searching for 'Mafia', 'Werewolf', or 'Moles' is a red herring in this case, I think.

These sorts of stories predate those games by a long, long time. The most reliable term I could think of that would probably best match is '[Murder Mystery Stories](https://www.goodreads.com/genres/murder-mystery)'.

The trouble will be narrowing it down such that all participants are known ahead of time-- I think the story that most comes to mind for this is something like CLUE, or perhaps Sherlock Holmes, depending on the style you're looking for.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'll try and look into it.

Answer (score 0):

The American Mafia is a criminal enterprise which may be viewed as distinct from the origins of the Sicilian Mafia. I recommend being clear on what you mean by 'mafia.'

In the 19th and 20th centuries, the American and Sicilian mafias may together have  been defined as:

> ... a network of organized-crime groups based in Italy and America,
> evolved over centuries in Sicily, an island ruled until the mid-19th
> century by a long line of foreign invaders. **Sicilians banded
> together in groups to protect themselves and carry out their own
> justice**. In Sicily, the term “mafioso,” or Mafia member, initially
> had no criminal connotations and was used to refer to a person who was
> suspicious of central authority.

I would think this might be the angle to contemplate if considering the history of a current-day monster, such as a werewolf.

Comment: I mean mafia/werewolf the genre. There's a link in the post. It's usually refers to a game where one has to discern who amongst the group is actually an enemy.

Answer (score -1):

It's been a bit since I read their article, but TVTropes.org also has an article for Werewolf that got me hooked.  They also have a subpage called "Characters"  which will list dedicated roles that may show up in a play through and what their function to the community is as well as alternative names (For example, while the game can be run homemade cards for players, the most popular box set lists one role as "The Little Girl" even though the role requires play that can be done by any character in a story regardless of gender or age.  For those interested, player who is given "The Little Girl" role is permitted by the game master to see the werewolves after their first attack, thus learning the identity of all three wolves.  However, the character realizes that if the wolves learn this, they will kill them, so they are barred by rules from directly outing the wolves... but may vote on which player to eliminate during the democracy portion of the game freely...  Thus the players who identify the "Little Girl" can watch for cues in how the player votes to determine if the person who is being accused is a werewolf... including the wolves presumably if a wolf ever identifies the "Little Girl" the player will surely be eliminated the next round) or similar roles that overlap (as a party game, many house rules exist to give lack luster roles a little extra or create new roles to replace old ones.  Depending on the group, these modifications either change a base role's abilities OR have both roles present because the creation is to make sure all the villagers have an ability OR eliminate other base roles based on roles in play).  I also believe they list the Mafia's equivalent names (The roles handle the same no matter the version you pull, Werewolf is themed to small town fantasy horror setting while Mafia is themed to a modern organized crime setting, thus role names are changed to fit the story.  For example, one role will allow a villager to discover the latest attack victim and heal them once per game, thus letting them nullify a kill.  In Werewolf, I believe the role is called "The Witch" and the thematic idea is that they either use magic to reserect the player or are making "magic" potions from natural ingredients that benefit the user's health... In Mafia, the role is "The Doctor" and represents a person who has medical knowledge finding the victim after the attack but before the vic succumbs to the wounds in a right place, right time.  In other versions of the game where the "Wolves" are a Coven of Witches (I suspect to drive the point of playing a game of witch hunt home a little better) the role will obviously get another name, since "Witch" is the name of the titular bad guys (I heard one version where the role was given the name "Good Samaritan" since the redress was set to a theme of the Salem Witch Hunts, and as such, the roles were given a quasi-mystical theme naming, but unlike Gothic Horror, the naming was given a Biblical/Religious theme... since Witches are linked to Satan in setting.